# .prop() versus .data()

Tags: jquery

With the new release of [jQuery v1.6](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.6/) and the addition of the `.prop()` method.

Is there an inherent difference in using `.prop()` over `.data()` ?

I see in the documentation that not removing a property can result in memory leaks in versions of IE prior to IE9. But are there any other performance issues or other issues with using the new `prop()` method?

Syntax from the site:

```
var $para = $("p");    
$para.prop("luggageCode", 1234);
```

Over the following:

```
var $para = $("p");
$para.data("luggageCode", 1234);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe prop is intended for setting valid HTML document properties, rather than arbitrary data. I'd suggest you continue to use data for luggageCode type info.

Comment: This is my thought as well but can you cite any docs that back up this claim? And this also doesn't answer the question about performance issues.

Comment: Also data("foo","bar") will set <element data-foo="bar"/> not <element foo="bar"/>

Comment: Actually `data("foo","bar")` will set the *data* on the jQuery object and **will not** set the HTML DOM element attribute (for that you would need `attr("data-foo", "bar")` [also `prop("data-foo", "bar")` **will not** add anything to the DOM]).

Comment: Clarification: the `data` method _can_ retrieve `data-*` attribute data, but it cannot change it. For example, if `<elm data-foo="foo" />` is in the DOM, `$("elm").data("foo")` will return `"foo"` unless `$("elm").data("foo", "bar")` is called first, then it would return `"bar"` and `<elm data-foo="foo" />` would remain unchanged. So it's best to use `attr` to get and set any `data-*` variables to eliminate possible confusion.

Answer (score 7):

I think it comes down to the difference between a property of the DOM Node, and a property of the Javascript object that represents it.

The documentation does not specify *how* or *where* `.data()` data is stored, so the fact that you're seeing it as a property of the relevant jQuery object may just be an implementation detail. jQuery would be permitted to store it absolutely anywhere else, too.

In contrast, `.prop()` of course relates explicitly to properties of the DOM Node.

Answer (score 3):

I may be going about this wrong, but it seems that `.data()` **can** be enumerated, while `.prop()` **cannot**.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4G2c3/)**

```
var $p = $("<p>");
    $p.data('luggagecode', '12345');
    $p.data('luggagecode_backup', '54321');

for (var key in $p.data()) { // generates two alerts
    var value = $p.data(key);
    alert('DATA | '+key+' = '+value);
}

var $p2 = $("<p>");
    $p2.prop('luggagecode', '12345');
    $p2.prop('luggagecode_backup', '54321');

for (var key in $p2.prop()) { // no alerts
    var value = $p2.prop(key);
    alert('PROP | '+key+' = '+value);
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you because you're on the right track, but properties can definitely be [enumerated](http://jsfiddle.net/h3uee/). I think you should revise this answer and say that `.data()` is for user defined data and `.prop()` actually adds/updates a property on the DOM element.