# Does jquery.data skip event handlers when storing an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across a strange scenario. I used jquery's data function to store a row element with several td columns and some event handlers on those columns.  When I try to retrieve that row element in another function I don't find the events in the data('events') on that element.

Do the event handlers get skipped while using jquery's data function?

Comment: showing a code example of what you're seeing would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing `data()` with `attr()` and `prop()`  potentially see [the jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) or [prop vs data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873631/prop-versus-data) or [prop vs attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

I can't think of a context where I would use `data()` to handle events.  I use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) by preference to set event handlers, and `unbind()` to remove them afterwards.

Using the html attribute `onclick="doSomeJavascriptThing();"` is not a very jQuery way of solving the problem. Inline javascript is probably considered a bit dirty these days.